# What differentiates these two window types in Windows/.NET?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, desktop

I've noticed certain desktop apps updating on Windows 10 to begin to use the new, nice looking window border that is themed consistent with the operating system.

For example, the Slack desktop app in the beta channel now looks like this:

[image: slack app]

I've blocked out personal information, but you can see the idea. Now, the window border of Firefox looks like this:

[image: firefox]

This was the default for a long time. What changed? I personally like the former and would love to know what changes have to be made to make apps fit the new cohesive theme.

I guess my question is, to clarify: **What part of the windows executable packaging scheme makes windows look like this? What would I have to do to build a basic program that had a window bar like this?**

Comment: It doesn't.  It draws its own window chrome instead of letting the OS do it.  The kind of work companies invest in when the look-and-feel is a major feature of an app and doesn't do much else.  Start with a borderless window, add a lot of code.  Lots of existing Q+A about this already, we don't need another one.  Thanks for trying to contribute.

Comment: I find that difficult to believe that that's really the case... a number of native Windows apps have the exact same theme (i.e. calculator, Edge, and other Windows store apps.) Did Slack _really_ draw its own window chrome, or is it using a Windows API?

Comment: The hamburger menu on the left is a good hint, not part of the chrome for a WinRT either.  But hey, you don't have to believe it.

Comment: The hamburger menu **is** part of the window chrome for a UWP app. I believe this was introduced with the Anniversary Update.

Comment: See, that's what I thought, but the Slack desktop app _isn't_ a UWP app, it's an Electron app. Do you think there is an API exposed to allow the window chrome to be modified by non-UWP apps, or is Slack really fully implementing a custom window frame that matches the UWP theme exactly?

Comment: For non-UWP apps I *think* the only way to get the Modern UI look is by going full custom non-client rendering. With a framework this doesn't appear to be unrealistic, even if it is a fair bit of work.